# No chill cubes storage

Tags: chilling, no-chill

How long can I store the wort in the no chill cube? Does it need to be used as soon as its cooled down or relatively quickly?

Comment: The longest I've gone is 3 weeks in the cube before pitching. The beer was a brown ale that turned out nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to your sanitation and process. You want to be filling those cubes **hot**. This means above 190ºF. This will, to a significant degree, sanitize the inside of the container and ensure that you'll be able to store it for a reasonable period of time. Many no chill brewers go for weeks or even months before pitching yeast.

Comment: When storing, do you need to make sure the cubes are 100% filled with liquid to avoid oxygen exposure or is that not as much of a concern with the wort?

Comment: If you plan to store the wort for a long time, you'll want to avoid exposure to oxygen.

Comment: Since a vacuum forms when the tank cools, I would think the expose to the oxygen in the headspace is somewhat minimized.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure I understand this. The volume of the wort and air shrink, which will create negative pressure on the cube. But, whatever's in there stays in there, assuming the seal is good (which it needs to be).